# Listing churches with their administrative location using Overpass

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, point-of-interest

I'd like to extract a list of churches from OSM with their name, their coordinates and the name of the lower administrative division they belong to. I managed to get the first ones with:

```
area["name"="Mayenne"]->.boundaryarea;
way(area.boundaryarea)["building"="church"];
out tags center;
```

*I deliberately ignore nodes and relations as they don't seem relevant in this case.*

I can't find a way to retrieve the name of the lower administrative division. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I suggest to search for `amenity=place_of_worship` as well. There are 864226 of them (nodes and ways), while `building=church` only has 200886. For the admin division, you have to look into `admin_level`. It depends on your study area how deep they are detailed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For the admin division, the problem is that I can't find a way to link the node/way/relation to `admin_level` or to perform reverse geocoding.

Comment: You have to do a spatial join between the buildings and admin polygons. Either use a postgis database, or any GIS software for that.

Comment: @AndreJ: you can use Overpass API `is_in` for that purpose, see below.

Answer (score 7):

Similar to an example in the [Overpass by Example](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example#Adding_Georeference_details_to_village_nodes_.28since_0.7.54.29) library, I'd suggest to use the following query:

```
[timeout:60];
area["name"="Mayenne"]->.boundaryarea;
way(area.boundaryarea)["building"="church"];
  foreach(
    node(w)->.n;
    .n is_in->.a;
    area.a[name][boundary=administrative][admin_level~"^[2-8]$"] -> .a;
    out center;
    convert way ::=::,
              ::id = id(),
              is_in=a.set("{" + t["admin_level"] + ":" + t["name"] + "}");
   
    out;
  );
```

**Step-by-step explanation how this query works:**

- It iterates over each `building=church` in your area
- determines all nodes for each building
- find out in which areas those nodes are (*this is the actual georeferencing step*)
- filter out all areas with `boundary=administrative` and admin_level between 2 and 8 (you can adjust those if needed).
- print out the center point of the church building way
- generates an artificial element with the same way id and an additional element `is_in`, which lists all administrative boundaries the church is in.
- prints out artificial element

Note that the query returns two ways for each church, one with a center node, and one with an `is_in` entry but without geometry. At this time, you have to manually merge those two ways. In a later version of Overpass API this will change, though, returning only one single result including geometry.

The line containing georeferencing information looks as follows:

Result is also available here for download: https://gist.github.com/mmd-osm/497252a37d174b187c7afc0238200fc5

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to output it to .csv with `[out:csv(::id,"name",::lat,::lon,::is_in;false)];`, but it never prints out the administrative boundaries. Any idea why?

Comment: the field name has to be "is_in", like "name". ::is_in doesn't exist as such, hence no result in the output.

Comment: I tried it also but it doesn't work either...

Comment: How do you expect the administrative boundaries to show up in CSV format? Here's how the result looks here: https://gist.github.com/mmd-osm/10e867cfcfbe15fcef65867e64b6630e

Comment: That's precisely what I wanted, thanks! How did you manage to print "is_in"?

Comment: Like I said before your csv string needs to change to "is_in" instead of ::is_in